# Set C# Property that has no Setter

Tags: c#, reflection

In C#, there is the `Exception` class. For the purposes of testing, I would like to be able to set its `StackTrace` property to arbitrary strings. `StackTrace` has no setter, so my first attempt was to try using reflection:

```
Exception instance = new Exception("Testing");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(Exception).GetProperty("StackTrace");
propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, "Sample StackTrace value", null);
```

This yields the runtime error:

`System.ArgumentException : Property set method not found.`

Is there any way I could set the `StackTrace` property? More generally, is there a way to set a property that lacks a setter?

Comment: You could use Reflector to find out what the backing variable is called for this property and then use reflection to set that.

Comment: How about extending your own exception class?

Comment: @Nick - there is no backing field: `return this.GetStackTrace(true);`

Comment: There is a backing field, actually. @Nick is correct in is assertion: `_stackTraceString` is settable via reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could derive your own exception class and override the `StackTrace` property, which is virtual:

```
public sealed class MyException: Exception
{
    public MyException(string message, string stackTrace): base(message)
    {
        _stackTrace = stackTrace;
    }

    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get
        {
            return _stackTrace;
        }
    }

    private readonly string _stackTrace;
}
```

Note that to do this properly, you should really implement all the standard exception constructors, but for unit testing this might not be strictly necessary.

See [Designing Custom Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details:

Comment: A good solution, but overriding all exceptions to use a custom exceptions class isn't feasible.

Comment: Well maybe you could also write a wrapper exception class just for test purposes.

Comment: That's true, creating my own Exception class in the testing library (internal to that library only) would probably be better than reflection.

Comment: is it normal in `C#` to be using `_paramName` for variable names ? O.o

Comment: @mmcrae It's pretty common for private fields. However, by typing "_paramName" you made it look like you were thinking about parameter names - and it is certainly NOT normal for those. The code I posted uses it for a private field, NOT a parameter. Some people use `this.` instead, and if using `_` there's an argument to be made to using it as a suffix instead.

Answer (score 2):

That property is implemented this way:

```
public virtual string StackTrace
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable, TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    get
    {
        return this.GetStackTrace(true);
    }
}
```

And that called method is implemented this way:

```
private string GetStackTrace(bool needFileInfo)
{
    string text = this._stackTraceString;
    string text2 = this._remoteStackTraceString;
    if (!needFileInfo)
    {
        text = this.StripFileInfo(text, false);
        text2 = this.StripFileInfo(text2, true);
    }
    if (text != null)
    {
        return text2 + text;
    }
    if (this._stackTrace == null)
    {
        return text2;
    }
    string stackTrace = Environment.GetStackTrace(this, needFileInfo);
    return text2 + stackTrace;
}
```

So it seems that if you set the field `_stackTraceString` to any `String`, you will get  `_stackTraceString` + `_remoteStackTraceString`.

You can set fields with [FieldInfo.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I got this information using http://ilspy.net.

**Do not do this on production.** Things are designed in a specific way for a reason, just the exposed API is guaranteed, a minor upgrade could change this internal implementation detail and break your code, so never rely on internal details, just exposed APIs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the backing field of the object:

```
Exception instance = new Exception("Testing");

var f = typeof(Exception).GetField("_stackTraceString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetField);

f.SetValue(instance, "hello");
```

This should work, to get a list of private fields you can use:

```
var fields = typeof(Exception).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Personally I prefer the solution proposed by Matthew Watson.

Answer (score 0):

The StackTrace property of an Exception object is set by the runtime during stack walk, so we cannot set it manually.