# Set property that has no setter with an internal constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, internal

I have a similiar problem as described in this topic: [Set C# Property that has no Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405217/set-c-sharp-property-that-has-no-setter)
The difference is that my Class has an internal constructor, so i have to create an instance like this:

```
 var _TxObjectImpl = (TxObjectImpl) typeof (TxObjectImpl).GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, Type.EmptyTypes, null).Invoke(null);
```

The Class has two Properties:

```
 public string StringId
        {
            get
            {...
            }
         return str;
        }

public object PlanningRepresentation
        {
            get
            {
                return ...;
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to set these properties and call the constructor as above at the same time?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Trespasser/

Comment: why would you even want to do that? since you specifically marked the variable as `readonly`. clearly it cannot be changed once its set up in the constructor

Comment: So you're asking how to construct and modify a class whose authors have gone through trouble of making sure you cannot construct or modify that class? What's next? Those authors asking a new question what they can change in their class to stop your code from working?

Comment: @alexo The question is very unclear and it took me several re-reads to get it, but no, the other question is about making the `StackTrace` property return something different, and accomplishes that by hard-coding the stack trace in the constructor. This question is how to adapt that code to work when the base class's constructor is inaccessible.

Comment: @hvd , the problem is that my task is urgent. The devs from the software i'm working on are in the same company, but i can't wait for a hotfix; this is just a temporarily workaround.

Comment: well, you could drop the `readonly` from the variable, implement your property to support `private setter`, and add a method to that class in which you could set the value. don`t know if that helps, but i'm kinda confused of what you are trying to achieve here with exactly this structure

Comment: The question is *very* unclear and the OP seems to misunderstand the question he links to. The answer there was "don't do that, derive your own exception!". The posted exception class is irrelevant to the question and *removing* it will be an improvement.

Comment: @Pepelee perhaps the quickest fix would be to ask your colleagues why they went to such lengths to prevent you from inheriting from this class. Are you sure there is a bug to fix? Perhaps you are using the class in the wrong way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The work is about a API of a CAD-Software, which you can use to create objects in your Project. Every Project needs for its creation a: "TxObjectImpl". There are CreationClasses in the API for several Object-Types, but few are not implemented yet. Thats why i'm trying to instantiateTxObjectImpl.

Comment: @Pepelee That explains why you're trying to instantiate it, but not why you're trying to derive from it and modify it.

Comment: @hvd the problem is that two properties of the TxObjectImpl throw a "System.AccessViolationExeption" after me creating it. I want to test if you can set them manually, but they have only Getter.

Answer (score 2):

You can't derive your class from a base class which doesn't have an accessible `public` or `protected` constructor.

If the base class implements an interface, you could use the [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern and create an instance of it with reflection as a private field of your new class.

Comment: Technically you can: as long as the class is not `sealed`, you can derive from it, insert two delegating constructors, where each delegates to the other. You can also make sure that terminates with a catchable exception. If you then construct the class and catch the exception, there's an object of that class somewhere, waiting to be garbage collected. Finally, override the destructor to resurrect the object and make it available somewhere. (Please, don't do this, I'm just saying it's *possible*.)

Comment: @hvd please note the exception in the question is actually irrelevant, it was copied from the accepted answer in the linked question that said "don't do that, create your own class"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, sorry for the confusion, i simplified my question.

Comment: @hvd You're referring to the technique from a recent Jon Skeet's blogpost if I'm not mistaking. I agree, don't **ever** do this.

Comment: @DamirArh I think I read it here on SO, but it wouldn't surprise me if it was written by Jon Skeet.